# Laravel 5 two questions

Tags: php, laravel

I'm laravel newbie and I have 2 questions:

**1.** How to set "From:" who in password reminder sent? Because nothing prints now:
[image]

**2.** How to insert custom value when registering?

I'm tried in AuthController but 0 emotions, nothing inserts:

Default:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I' tried but not works:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'seo_name' => str_slug($data['name']),
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

But nothing happened. Why? Thanks in advance ;)

P.S I have `seo_name` row in PhpMyAdmin and I want when registration successfull insert for example:

**name** - Custom Name

**seo_name** - custom-name (str_slug function makes that string, but IDK how to insert..)

Comment: Please don’t ask multiple questions in a single Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How to set "From:" who in password reminder sent? Because nothing prints now

In Laravel, you can make use of the SwiftMailer library by using the Mail class. This will give you access to commands such as  `$message->from('youremail@emailaddress.com', 'Firstname Lastname');`

Here's an example -

```
Mail::send('emails.emailview', $data, function($message) {
    $message->from('youremail@emailaddress.com', 'Firstname Lastname');

    $message->to('to@emailaddress.com')->cc('anotherperson@emailaddress.com');
});
```

> 2. How to insert custom value when registering?

You'll have to update your User model with the new field in the `$fillable` property. This should reflect the name of the table that you've added for the new field.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array('id', 'password');

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'seo_name', 'email');

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, with first question: http://i.imgur.com/s258uTM.png as you see every mail has title, for example "Facebook", "World Of Tanks" but my is null. In PHP exists function like "From: mymail@mail.com" like `<?php mail("toemail@gmail.com", "subject", "message", "From: mygmail.com");` and then it prints From: mygmail.com not null

Answer (score 0):

for inserting the custom value the above mentioned method `$fillable` is required.Put `$fillable` on to your model and add the fields are to be needed to insert.

eg.

```
$this->db->table('tb_name')->create([name => $value,
                                        address => $val,
                                        ...
                                   ]);
```

then you add protected `$fillable = array('name', 'address', ...);`